# Get img currentSrc from srcset before the image is downloaded

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, srcset

I am in the process of writing an image preloader for Vue.js. The way I intend it to work is by scraping the DOM for any `img` elements and obtaining their `currentSrc` attribute, before looping through and preloading each of the images.

Consider the following basic example:

```
const images = [];

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Scrape the DOM for any images
    document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(item => {

        images.push(item.currentSrc);

    });

    // Run the preload script...
    preload(images);

});
```

### The Issue

The problem with the above method is that the `img` elements have not yet decided what the `currentSrc` is based on `srcset`.

Is there a way, or an event to listen for, to be able to access `currentSrc` **before** the image has actually been downloaded?

**Note** - `window.load` is not appropriate because it waits until the images have loaded

*I do not actually believe this is possible, in which case, I will have to write some JS to interpret the `srcset` and `sizes` attribute of the `img` elements in order to determine the anticipated `currentSrc`.*

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a native way to do this so I wrote the JS to interpret the source images. In my case I can assume the images are sorted from small to large and that there is a fallback img tag at the bottom

Here's a working demo I made https://jsfiddle.net/mattbucci/x1h5pb4z/96/

```
var vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
console.log('browser width is ' + vw);

var picture = document.getElementsByClassName('picture-element')[0];
var images = picture.children

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
 var image = images[i]; 
 var matches = null;
 if (image.media !== undefined) {
     matches = image.media.match(/\(max-width:(.*)px\)/);
 } else {
     console.log('found fallback image ' + image.src)
     console.log(image.src + ' is being loaded')
     var preload = new Image();
     preload.src = image.src;
     preload.onload = () => { console.log('loaded ' + preload.src)}
 }

 if (matches && matches[1]) {
    var maxWidth = parseInt(matches[1].trim());
    console.log('found responsive image ' + image.srcset)
    console.log('image should be loaded below width ' + maxWidth);

    if (vw < maxWidth) {
      console.log(image.srcset + ' is being loaded')
      var preload = new Image();
      preload.src = image.srcset;
      preload.onload = () => { console.log('loaded ' + preload.src)}
      break;
    }
 }
}
```